# Template class error in CP

Tags: templates, ee2-upgrades

Recently I upgraded an EE2 website to EE5. After upgrade, everything working very well except I am getting error while trying to edit/create a template from CP or from Template Manager -> Template Settings. For error message, please see screenshot - 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So that is an `E_NOTICE` level warning, not a fatal error. You are seeing this because you either have debugging forced in your `index.php` for you Control Panel, have it hard-coded in your `config.php` file, or have it turned on in Output and Debugging in Control Panel.

If you still get a rendered page at `Template Manager -> Template Settings` past the notice and it isn't working, it is **because** you have debugging forced on. This is possibly causing the related rendered JavaScript assets to also have that notice, causing a broken JS asset to be loaded. Just one possibility.

I have noticed these issues in EE4 and EE5 when using the template manager, but they appear harmless, as `E_NOTICE` level warnings often are; most full application and their relevant technology stacks can output warnings and notices and log them as well, and be fully functional. Also remember that EE can run on a pretty wide range of PHP and MySQL versions, and that can be very relevant as to what warnings and notices you may get.

If you are truly concerned, contact EllisLab about this, but there is a good change they will tell you to turn off debugging and ignore this notice. You also shouldn't be running a production application with debugging on, ever.